# Updating Python 3.8 not updating pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

On Mac Catalina 10.15.4  i had python 3.7 installed using homebrew. Uninstalled it and installed 3.8 using installer( not brew ) . Updated pip and when i checked the version it is showing the warning `pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper` and advice me to use it with `-m` flag, and is showing the folder as `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip(python 3.7)` the version that i removed . I tried to uninstall pip using `python3 -m pip uninstall pip` and i am getting the following folders are going to be removed

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip3.8`

ie; the newly installed version .

Is there a way to remove the old pip and use the one with 3.8 .

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out this problem by uninstalling the 3.8 version i installed using installer and installed the same version  using homebrew . Then i updated my .zshrc with `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"` making it the default for python3 . I had to revert back because so many programs just stopped working , like vim , mycli etc:- so i resorted to the easy way .

If somebody have the answer to install python3.8 from installer without harming other programs using python ( i have lots of them installed using brew and they will be looking for brew python) please let me know  . It would have been great if those who have voted down have given their reasons in comments so that i can step back from repeating such mistakes .

Thanking all ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only issue was an incorrect version in the Shebang of `/usr/local/bin/pip` , which was referencing the old Python version (3.7).

The following worked for me:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```